# How to force download a file when get file path in ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, file

I want to download file on my server i have the following code that i tried but file is not downloading. i am merging multiple files into single file then after merger i want the result file to download. Now files merger in result.docx but not download automatically

i am returning complete file path in ajax response

Script

```
        $("#download_specs").click(function(){

            var slug = this.getAttribute('data-id');

            $.ajax({
                url:"{{url('merge-document')}}",
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
                data:{slug:slug} ,

                success:function(data){

                var zz=document.createElement('a');
                zz.href = data;
                }
            });
        });
```

Controller

```
    public function mergeDocuments(Request $request){

        $project_slug  = $request->input('slug');

        $userID = Auth::user()->id;
        $files = DB::table('project_specs_files')->select('completed_specs')->where('user_id',$userID)->where('project_slug',$project_slug)->get();

        $specs_array = array();
        foreach($files as $file){

            $ext = pathinfo(public_path(). '\\uploads\\complete_specs\\'.$userID.'\\files\\'.$file->completed_specs, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            if($ext == 'docx'){
                if (file_exists(public_path(). '\\uploads\\complete_specs\\'.$userID.'\\files\\'.$file->completed_specs)){

                    $specs_array[] =  public_path(). '\\uploads\\complete_specs\\'.$userID.'\\files\\'.$file->completed_specs ;
                }       
            } 
        }
        if(!empty($specs_array)){
            $dir = public_path(). '\\uploads\\complete_specs\\'.$userID.'\\files\\';
            $dm = new DocxMerge();
            $dm->merge($specs_array, $dir.'result.docx' );
        }else{

            return 'Files not supported for merge';
        }

        return $dir.'result.docx';

    }
```

in return i m receiving `'D:\xampp\zerodocs\public\uploads\complete_specs\4\files\result.docx'`

Comment: `success:function(data){ document.location = data; }` works, depending on the server - though - your server is not responding with a URL that is accessible from the browser - so that is what you have to fix

Comment: tried this solution but not worked

Comment: it wasn't a solution, and the problem is with the result sent back by the server ... a browser can't access that path (except a browser running on the server) ... in other words - the server is sending the wrong URL (it's not even sending a URL)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is using the browser to download it instead of using javascript fs as it has the risk of data corruption.
This function creates a href tag and clicks it to init download. Hope that helps

```js
function _downloadUrlContent(url) {
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = url;
    a.download = '';
    a.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
  }
```

Comment: maybe will be needed adding an attribute `download`, because of a browser can just open the file instead of download

Comment: used your solution like this but not working`
  $("#download_specs").click(function(){
  
   var slug = this.getAttribute('data-id');

   $.ajax({
    url:"{{url('merge-document')}}",
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
     'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    data:{slug:slug} ,

    success:function(data){
     alert(data);
     const a = document.createElement('a');
     a.href = data;
     a.download = '';
     a.style.display = 'none';
     document.body.appendChild(a);
     a.click();
     document.body.removeChild(a);} }); }); `

Comment: Ivan is right here download attribute is needed for certain files that don't download by default. Also, Abdullah, I have updated the code hope it works out for you now.

Comment: `window.location = url` should be enough with the appropriate download headers on the file link